# django photologue on webfaction

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, webfaction, photologue

I think I've got an issue described in the [photologue docs](http://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/installation.html#that-troublesome-pillow) regarding having both PIL and Pillow installed at the same time. Webfaction has PIL installed by default and I can't seem to uninstall it. The docs say "write a temporary file /tmp/PHOTOLOGUE_NO_PILLOW" but I'm not sure if that's a file or a directory or where to put it.

EDIT: Thanks to rajasimon I correctly put the file in temp and now there is no Pillow to conflict with PIL (I tested and cannot import Pillow but can import PIL) but still the same error when it attempts to automatically resize a photo:

```
Exception Type: UnsupportedOperation at /admin/photologue/photo/add/
Exception Value: fileno
```

What is the best way to install photologue on webfaction?

Photologue installs fine but then I get the following error when I try to add an image:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://passiveaggressivenews.twoifiplay.com/admin/photologue/photo/add/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'taggit',
 'panews',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_bleach',
 'django_wysiwyg',
 'django_social_share',
 'photologue',
 'sortedm2m')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  584.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1454.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1405.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/home/nlivni/webapps/passiveaggressivenews/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1046.         obj.save()
File "/home/nlivni/lib/python2.7/photologue/models.py" in save
  540.         super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nlivni/lib/python2.7/photologue/models.py" in save
  492.         self.pre_cache()
File "/home/nlivni/lib/python2.7/photologue/models.py" in pre_cache
  473.                 self.create_size(photosize)
File "/home/nlivni/lib/python2.7/photologue/models.py" in create_size
  455.             raise e

Exception Type: UnsupportedOperation at /admin/photologue/photo/add/
Exception Value: fileno
```

I haven't been able to turn up anything that appears similar and the docs refer to "strange bugs" and this seems like that. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind `tmp/` is a directory ..

> This directory contains mostly files that are required temporarily

Access your dedicated server using terminal and access the folder using `cd /tmp` . After using touch to create new file

```
>touch PHOTOLOGUE_NO_PILLOW
```

Comment: thanks, that worked in not installing Pillow but I still have the same error even though I have only PIL :(

Comment: @twoifiplay hope it worked . ! they tell u to install again right ?

Comment: it worked and I reinstalled photologue but still the same error. it works locally with PIL and with Pillow but still does not work on webfaction. I'm going to give up on it for now and try django-imagekit.

Comment: good .. but tried to fix it .. ! that's d good spirit...  for your reference pls see this link https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/issues/243

Comment: thanks @rajasimon! imagekit is working great and has no issues. much appreciated.

Comment: @twoifiplay my answer only solve your pillow issue only .. but you managed to install imagekit .. glad that worked. ..